# JQuery offset returns undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, navigation

I have a Rails app. There is a view containing:

```
<nav class="navigation" id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#address">Address</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Website</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

A custom.js file in my app/assets/javascript folder containing:

```
var mediaTop = $('div#navigation').offset();
var media = $('div#navigation');
console.log(mediaTop);

$(document).scroll( function() {
   var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();


   //fix/unfix as necessary
   if (mediaTop < scrollTop) {
       $(media).addClass('fixed'); 
   }
   else { 
       $(media).removeClass('fixed'); 
   }
});
```

The console line is printing out undefined, however. The jQuery code is supposed to lock the navigation bar to the top of the page when i scroll down and it's top edge hits the top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The console line is printing out undefined, however.

I find that surprising. I'm not aware of a situation where `offset` returns `undefined`. `null`, yes, but not `undefined`.

Two main things:

First, if the `console.log` line is showing `null`, it's because the `#navigation` element doesn't exist yet. Ensure that your code doesn't run until *after* the element exist, by moving your script to below the element in the HTML, or using jQuery's `ready`.

Perhaps `undefined` is used in some cases where the element is hidden, as the documentation says

> jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with `visibility:hidden` set, `display:none` is excluded from the rendering tree and thus has a position that is undefined.

(But in my experiments, I still got a position even with `display: none`, rather than getting `undefined`.)

Secondly, `offset` returns an object with two properties: `left` and `top`. You want `top`.

Also, there's no need to look up the element twice. Just reverse the order of your first two statements.

Taking all that together:

```
// Make sure this is run *after* the element exists, and make sure it's not hidden
var media = $('div#navigation');
var mediaTop = media.offset().top;
```

---

You asked below how to use `ready` with your external script file: You just put your call in the `ready` callback, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

or the shortcut

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

But you only have to do that if you *don't* control where your `script` tag goes (e.g., you're writing a library or something). If you *do* control it, just put the `script` tag [at the end of the document](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<!-- ...page content... -->
<script src="myfile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think ready is the answer. How would I use it in my separate jQuery file?

Comment: @delisdeli: There's not usually any reason to use `ready` unless you don't control the location of your `script` tag (e.g., writing plugins or libraries). Just put the `script` tag at the very bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` element. However, if you want to use `ready`, just call your code from the `ready` callback: `$(document).ready(function() { /* ...your code here... */ });` or use the shortcut: `$(function() { /* ...your code here... */});`

Answer (score -1):

**Replace**

```
var mediaTop = $('div#navigation').offset();
```

**with**

```
var mediaTop = $('div#navigation').offset().top;
```

[**Official Document**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: Although the OP *does* want `top` (not `Top`), if the line is showing `undefined`, that's not the main problem.

Comment: well since offset returns undefined in this case calling .top on that gives me the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Top' of undefined". Also shouldn't it be a lowercase top?