# JS - link to homepage with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

on my prestashop web page I have "one-page" homepage with anchors. I use class linkscroll and JS script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.onas').attr('id', 'onas');
});
$(".linkscroll a").on('click', function(event) {
  if (this.hash !== "") {
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  }
});
```

On homepage everything working properly. But when I'm on product page, no action after click on this link. Href is: "index.php#onas"

In console I see error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (20-12-x-500ml-ekolok.html:1197)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (core.js:39)
at HTMLAnchorElement.g.handle (core.js:39)
```

You can see here: https://ekolok.cz/ekolok/20-12-x-500ml-ekolok.html

Do you any solution how to repair it?
Thank you.

After comments I've edited code like this, but issue still appears:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.onas').attr('id', 'onas');
  
  $(".linkscroll a").on('click', function(event) { 
                                                                                                
     if(this.hash) {
     
      event.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){
   
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } 
  }); 
 });
```

Comment: Welcome!
Please add `jQuery` or whatever library you are using to the question's tags.
Thank you.

Comment: It appears that your `this.hash` is `undefined`. I think you should put your `click` event within the `document.ready`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add `click` event do `document.ready`, but same issue.

Comment: please add `if(this.hash)` instead of `if (this.hash !== "")`

Comment: Thank you @AnandBhushan, I edited as you wrote, but same issue.

Comment: @TomášZmuda does your `this.hash` element has `display:'none'` applied to it?
https://api.jquery.com/offset/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951670/jquery-offset-returns-undefined have a look.